# Reference custom field instead of Name in outputlink

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field, outputlink

I have an outputlink in visualforce page that uses a custom field as a display name of link instead of `Name` field. Link successfully displays when `Name` is used. However, I tried using other custom field named `Field1__c`, but link does not appear. Why is that?

By the way, `Field1__c` is a formula text field concatenating the `Name` standard field and a custom number field. Also, `Field1__c` has a value when viewed in record detail page.

**Visualforce**:

```
<!--portion-->
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!customList}" var="c" rendered="{!customList != null}">
   <apex:column headerValue="Custom Record">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!c.Id}">{!c.Field1__c}</apex:outputLink>
   </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

**Controller**

```
public class CustomController{

    public List<Contact> contactList{get;set;}
    public List<Custom__c> customList{get;set;}
    public Account accRecord;
    public CustomController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.accRecord = (Account)controller.getRecord();
        accRecord = [SELECT New_Field__c FROM Account WHERE Id=: accRecord.Id];
        customList = new List<Custom__c>();

        contactList = new List<Contact>();
        if(accRecord.New_Field__c != null){
            contactList = [SELECT Id,Name,Custom__c,Custom__r.Field1__c FROM Contact WHERE New_Field__c =: accRecord.New_Field__c];

            if(contactList.size()==0){
                contactList = null;
            }else{

                for(Contact c : contactList){

                    customList.add(new Custom__c(Id=c.Custom__c, Name = c.Custom__r.Custom_Name__c));

                }

                if(customList.size() == 0){
                    customList = null;
                }
            }
        }     
    }

}
```

**Modified Apex Class:**

```
public class CustomController{

    public List<Contact> contactList{get;set;}
    public List<CustomWrapper> customList {get;set;}
    public Account accRecord;
    public CustomController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.accRecord = (Account)controller.getRecord();
        accRecord = [SELECT New_Field__c FROM Account WHERE Id=: accRecord.Id];
        customList = new List<CustomWrapper>();

        contactList = new List<Contact>();
        if(accRecord.New_Field__c != null){

            contactList = [SELECT Id,Name,Custom__c,Custom__r.Field1__c, Custom__r.Custom_Name__c FROM Contact WHERE New_Field__c =: accRecord.New_Field__c];

            if(contactList.size()==0){
                contactList = null;
            }else{

                Map<Id, CustomWrapper> customMap = new Map<Id, CustomWrapper>();

                for(Contact c : contactList){
                    Custom__c customObj = new Custom__c(Id=c.Custom__c, Name = c.Custom__r.Custom_Name__c);
                    CustomWrapper wrapper = new CustomWrapper(customObj, c.Custom__r.Field1__c);
                    customMap.put(customObj.Id, wrapper);
                }

                customList = customMap.values();
                if(customList.size() == 0){
                    customList = null;
                }
            }
        }     
    }

    public class CustomWrapper {

        public Custom__c customObj {get; set;}
        public String fieldValue {get; set;}

        public CustomWrapper(Custom__c customObj, String fieldValue) {
            this.customObj = customObj;
            this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code refers `{!c.Field__c}` and you want value from `Field1__c`. Please update your post if that's not what your actual code looks like.

Comment: Apologies! I've modified the code just now. But still, link does not appear.

Comment: Is `Field1__c` visible in Field-Level Security to the user viewing the page?

Comment: Yes, I made sure it is visible in field-level security.

Comment: Can you please post your controller code as well?

Comment: @jagmohan I've just added the controller. Kindly see modified post.

Comment: @curdual Please refer my answer. And please let me know if that works or not.

Comment: @jagmohan I've included `Field1__c` in my query. But putting it in the new custom list results to error: `Field is not writeable`. Makes sense because this is  a formula field, as described on my post.

Comment: @curdual I have updated my answer. Please use a wrapper class to wrap `Custom__c` object and add any non writable fields as properties to that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the update controller code. I have added comments to code where you aren't querying fields which is why its `Field1__c` is not showing up on page. I also added a recommendation to use `Map` to collect unique records.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="CustomController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!customList}" var="c" rendered="{!customList != null}">
                <apex:column headerValue="Custom Record">
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!c.customObj.Id}">{!c.fieldValue}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public class CustomController {

    public List<Contact> contactList{get;set;}
    public List<CustomWrapper> customList {get;set;}
    public Account accRecord;

    public CustomController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.accRecord = (Account)controller.getRecord();
        accRecord = [SELECT New_Field__c FROM Account WHERE Id=: accRecord.Id];
        customList = new List<CustomWrapper>();

        contactList = new List<Contact>();
        if(accRecord.New_Field__c != null){
            // on this line you were not querying Custom_Name__c field, I have added that
            contactList = [
                SELECT Id, Name, Custom__c, Custom__r.Field1__c, 
                Custom__r.Custom_Number__c, Custom__r.Custom_Name__c 
                FROM Contact 
                WHERE New_Field__c =: accRecord.New_Field__c
            ];

            if(contactList.size()==0){
                contactList = null;
            }else{
                // recommend putting objects in a map to avoid duplicates
                Map<Id, CustomWrapper> customMap = new Map<Id, CustomWrapper>();
                // fixed a typo from Contat to Contact
                for(Contact c : contactList){
                    Custom__c customObj = new Custom__c(Id=c.Custom__c, Name = c.Custom__r.Custom_Name__c);
                    CustomWrapper wrapper = new CustomWrapper(customObj, c.Custom__r.Field1__c);
                    customMap.put(customObj.Id, wrapper);
                }
                // assign objects to list
                customList = customMap.values();
                if(customList.size() == 0){
                    customList = null;
                }
            }
        }     
    }

    public class CustomWrapper {

        public Custom__c customObj {get; set;}
        // use wrapper class property for formula field
        public String fieldValue {get; set;}

        public CustomWrapper(Custom__c customObj, String fieldValue) {
            this.customObj = customObj;
            this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. However, I've tried this also last time, and since `Field1__c` is a formula field, saving the controller would result to this error: `Field is not writeable`.

Comment: I've just used your code as a reference, but upon saving the controller, I am encountering error `Variable does not exist: customObj` on this line: `customMap.put(customObj.Id, wrapper);`

Comment: @curdual Can you please update your controller code in the question with the latest one you have in your org?

Comment: Modified controller has been added to the post. I just followed the sample you provided.

Comment: @curdual There is typo in the code. This line has extra closing bracket `Custom__c customObj = new Custom__c(Id=c.Custom__c, Name = c.Custom__r.Custom_Name__c));`. Please change it to `Custom__c customObj = new Custom__c(Id=c.Custom__c, Name = c.Custom__r.Custom_Name__c);`

Comment: I've omitted the extra right parentheses from the code. But error is still there, but this time, points to `customObj` of this line: `CustomWrapper wrapper = new CustomWrapper(customObj, c.Custom__r.Field1__c);`

Comment: @curdual I have updated my answer. I have tested this code in my org and it works.

Comment: Used again your code as reference, and it is working now! Thank you very much for your help and effort! :)